# NextAuth: Multiple users for one account

Tags: typescript, authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

I was **wondering if there was any way to have multiple users for one account provider.**
In this case, have a session which has a field to precise the active user (the one on which you're logged) and be able to **switch easily between users with a menu.**

Someone has any resource to achieve that or even if it's possible natively ?

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer, no, there are no built-in features specified in the [next-auth documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/introduction) that do multiple users for one account.

However, the sky is the limit and this would be a really cool feature for you to implement and not so difficult. The real beauty of next-auth is to be the foundation for these kinds of cool features, not to be a full service like Firebase.

I suppose that what you are trying to accomplish is something like Netflix where you have 1 account and inside you can create 'sub-users'.

What would be a good solution for this problem is what you are describing. You have a specific field that points to a list of sub-users for that account. You then can [CRUD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CRUD) (Create, Read, Update and Delete) sub-users easily by modifying that list.

E.g.
You could use a database [adapter](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/overview), for example [MongoDB](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/mongodb), where you would add a new field, a list of sub-users IDs. Then you could ask the user which sub-user to use. After you get the ID it is exactly like a normal user, you query by ID and get the sub-user data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I'll try my best to do something. However, i'm really concerned about the potential security issues linked to this idea.

Comment: What security issues do you foresee? IMHO, since you are using next-auth as your underlying library for managing the session and auth, you would benefit from all the security protocols they offer, which are extremely secure. E.g. Refresh tokens for a specific amount of time, and much more. Check [here](https://next-auth.js.org/faq#security) for any doubts.

Comment: I'm a bit worried on the verification that the active sub user really belongs to the parent user. For instance, in the session Object, the field activeUser precises an unique id to indicate the user currently active. Then, with this id, fetching information about this user is possible. But imagine that this session field is corrupted and the id provided is not the right one. The user will receive information from an unwanted user. However, if next auth manages all of those potential security issues that's fine ! I'll take a look at your link

Comment: That's a valid concern. We would have to discuss a bit further how the field could be corrupted but in short, with a refreshToken, you could solve this issue with next-auth. Also, if you feel like I answered your question, consider accepting it as an answer :)

Comment: (I'm using a classic SQL workflow and not an JWT). Yes a discussion could be a very interesting point !

Comment: But i think that the only possibility is to turn into SSR the process.

Comment: I've read an other time the whole documentation of NextAuth. In my workflow, NextAuth checks every time that the session is valid and as a consequence we cannot change in a malicious way some fields of the session Object. That's the reason why in this example [https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/role-based-login-strategy], the provided code is enough and as consequence a verification section of the role field is not required because next auth already did it.

Comment: Well i can't find a proper way to do it